# Connecting to Azure service bus through proxy - Java

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to implement the Azure service bus with help of java to receive messages from the queue but I am unable to connect to the service bus because of a proxy, I am getting a connection time exception i.e.

> Microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ServiceBusException: Error{condition=proton:io, description='Connection timed out: no further information', info=null}

and when I am trying it from my local network(without proxy) it is connecting to azure bus without any problem. I am using the same sample code which Microsoft has provided on GitHub i.e. [QueuesWithProxy.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/Java/azure-servicebus/QueuesWithProxy/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/samples/queueswithproxy/QueuesWithProxy.java).

How to configure proxy for azure service bus using java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056858/azure-service-bus-access-using-java-sdk-connectivity-mode

Answer (score 1):

I try to connect to Microsoft for this problem so I find out that the previous version of queue client supports ConnectivityMode using TCP, HTTP, HTTPS, and AutoDetect. ServiceBus Explorer is using AutoDetect, trying TCP first and then failing over to HTTPS, regardless of the transport mode we were using (SBMP or AMQP).
With the new client this has changed. TransportMode now combines both options and offers Amqp (AMQP over TCP) or AmqpWebSockets (AMQP over WebSockets). There's no AutoDetect mode. You will have to create your clients and specify TransportType as AmqpWebSockets to bypass blocked.